# .Net SqlDataReader Item is Null [VB]

Tags: .net, vb.net, null, sqldatareader

Ok, this is strange. I ran into this issue tonight when I was adding a feature for our corporate site.

I'm building a custom calendar control that queries our database to display corporate events. Here is the situation, there is an `EndDate` value stored and on the dev system one of the events have a `NULL` value. No big deal since it's only a test system, but might as well check before trying to use it anyway on the safe side. I figured the following code would work:

```
While dr.Read()
  corporateTable.Rows.Add(New Object() { _
    Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")) _
    , IIf(dr("EventEndDate") Is DBNull.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")).AddDays(1), Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventEndDate"))) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventType")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventDescription")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventMessage")) _
  })
End While
```

But it didn't, I still kept getting the `Object cannot be cast from DBNULL` error. So I thought it over and came up with this code which works successfully, although I don't like it and think it's ugly.

```
While dr.Read()
  Dim column As Integer = 0
  While column < dr.FieldCount - 1
    If dr.GetName(column) = "EventEndDate" Then
      Exit While
    End If

    column += 1
  End While
  corporateTable.Rows.Add(New Object() { _
    Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")) _
    , IIf(dr.IsDBNull(column), Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")).AddDays(1), dr.Item(column)) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventType")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventDescription")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventMessage")) _
  })
End While
```

The thing that really gets me is, at one point I had this:

```
, IIf(dr.IsDBNull(column), Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")).AddDays(1), Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventEndDate"))) _
```

Thinking that it should work because it should only evaluate the `dr()` if it's not `NULL`. However, it kept erroring out at the end because the value was in fact `NULL`.

So to finally get to my question, sorry for the long explanation.

Why is it that even though I'm checking if it's `NULL` before using the value, it errors out at the part that doesn't get called unless it's not `NULL`? Does it have to do with the fact that I'm using the `IIF()` and it's evaluating the whole statement? Or, using the `dr()`, it evaluates at runtime?

I'm just stumped and would like to know what exactly is going on, so if it's possible, come up with a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IIf` always evaluates both the true and false parts - use inline `If` instead if you want to avoid this:

```
While dr.Read()
  corporateTable.Rows.Add(New Object() { _
    Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")) _
    , If(dr("EventEndDate") Is DBNull.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventBeginDate")).AddDays(1), Convert.ToDateTime(dr("EventEndDate"))) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventType")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventDescription")) _
    , Convert.ToString(dr("EventMessage")) _
  })
End While
```

Comment: You might also try to make an extension method(s) using this approach: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html

Comment: @Will: I always get a laugh out of this as the function `IIf` is short for **immediate if**, which couldn't be further from the truth. Unless you interpret it as immediately evaluating both conditions. =)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it hangs up the page. I'll keep that in mind though for the future.

Comment: @Yuck - LOL, likewise, it's a shame it wasn't a proper inline-if from the outset.

Comment: @Kyle - it's highly unlikely that the `If(...)` is responsible for hanging up the page - you're sure it hangs and doesn't error?

Comment: Yup, I took out the `While column` and replaced the `IIF()` with the `If()` and the page wouldn't even load. Debugged it and it just hangs. Doesn't error out either.

Comment: @Kyle - note that my code doesn't use `dr.IsDBNull` - instead it compares to DBNull.Value.

Comment: I changed it to that, I don't know why it would just hang though. Very interesting...

Comment: Which version of .Net are you running against?

Comment: If you're using .Net 2, how are you using the If operator?  That was not available until VB version 9.

Comment: @Will A technically speaking you're correct, I was just wondering `why` that was happening cause I was curious. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Iif function is evaluating each statement, use a different construct for your null check such as [The IF function](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/ifop.htm)